# Kubernetes zero downtime redeploy with probes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, istio, kubernetes-pod

I am trying to achieve zero downtime deployment process, but it is not working.

My deployment has one replica. The pod probes look like this:

```
livenessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /health/live
    port: 80
  initialDelaySeconds: 15
  periodSeconds: 20
readinessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /health/ready
    port: 80
  initialDelaySeconds: 15
  periodSeconds: 20
```

During deployment, accessing pod returns 503 for at least 10 seconds. Questions I have:

- what might be wrong?
- how can I debug this?
- where can I see logs from a service that is probing my service?

Running `describe` on the pod I get:

```
Liveness:       http-get http://:80/health/live delay=5s timeout=1s period=2s #success=1 #failure=3
Readiness:      http-get http://:80/health/ready delay=5s timeout=1s period=2s #success=1 #failure=3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in

```
kind: Service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: maintenance-api
    version: "1.0.0"
    stage: #{Release.EnvironmentName}#
    release: #{Release.ReleaseName}#
```

if selector is sth like  #{Release.ReleaseName}# which changes every release then its like the old pod cannot be found so when release starts service is disconnecting from pod and only after the new pod finish deploying the service will start redirecting to it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [RollingUpdate](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/update/update-intro/) strategy in your `Deployment` in addition to probes :

```
strategy:
  type: RollingUpdate
  rollingUpdate:
     maxUnavailable: 25%
     maxSurge: 1
```

Interesting global example [here](https://medium.com/platformer-blog/enable-rolling-updates-in-kubernetes-with-zero-downtime-31d7ec388c81)

Comment: I had this type: RollingUpdate in my yaml without rollingUpdate, added this but no change, still when deploying then for at least 8 secs I get 503

Comment: additional the link you attached has few mistakes i lost time because of it